# VB.Net startup form immediately quits

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The startup form for my VB.Net application I am developing using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 appears for a very brief period then disappears.

The startup form I have is a "launch pad" whence users can select different application options. I have set the Startup form value in the Application properties window.

I am also using Application Events to launch a window to gather user credentials. If the credentials are correct, then the startup form should show. Otherwise, the user will be prompted to enter their information again, or they can quit the application altogether. Here is my startup code; I am setting up some other values within this logic.

```
 Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        Dim sysLogon As New SYSLogon
        sysLogon.ShowDialog()
        _currentUser = sysLogon.UserData
        _currentAlias = _currentUser
        _systemData = New StaticData()

    End Sub
```

The login window appears as expected, but after entering valid credentials, I only see a quick flash of the startup form and then the application quits. I have wrapped both the startup and the form load code in try/catch blocks, and I have not discovered anything out of the ordinary.

I've cleaned the build, deleted and rebuilt the pdb files, and have tried both debug and release builds. Are there other settings I am missing that could resolve this issue? I have not changed the startup form nor the application events file recently - these were working previously, the only difference being I had stepped away from this project for a couple of weeks.

The following is what is called immediately after a successful login:

```
 Private Sub LaunchPad_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CenterToScreen()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code that is being executed after the correct login?

Comment: I added this information at the end of the post.

Comment: There's a property for that: StartPosition.  Where do you "show" the form _systemData?  Your code looks like a person not logging in correctly can still get to that form though.

Comment: _systemData is not a form, it's a ReadOnly property used to reduce round trips to the database. For instance, there are lists used in various comboboxes throughout the application. These lists do not change so rather than going back and forth to the DB, I put them in memory and use them as appropriate.

Comment: So your Startup Form in the Application tab is set to your LaunchPad form?  A form flashing like that sounds like your form isn't running with a message loop.

Comment: Correct, LaunchPad is the Startup Form. I set shutdown mode to "When last form closes." I also just tried using Main() with the same results.

Comment: `Sub Main()
       Dim sysLogon As New SYSLogon
       sysLogon.ShowDialog()
       _currentUser = sysLogon.UserData
       _currentAlias = _currentUser
       _systemData = New StaticData()
       Application.EnableVisualStyles()
       Application.Run(New LaunchPad)

    End Sub`

Comment: I don't see any `LaunchPad.Show()` in your code. How is the form showed?

Comment: Delete the `obj` and `bin` folders in your project.  These will be rebuit when you build the project.  The 'obj` folder contents can become corrupted and prevent proper building of the project.  You can not have the project open when deleting these folders.

Comment: A dialog must always have an owner window.  If it doesn't, like it does not here, then there is no window left after you close it.  That forces the OS to find another window to move into the foreground, it will belong to another application.  Like Visual Studio.  Your main window eventually appears, but it will be behind that window.  Easy to misinterpret as "it quits".

Comment: The form is showed as a result of      Application.Run(New LaunchPad) for Main or as a result of setting it as the startup form when using ApplicationEvents. Or at least that's how it works on my other applications. If the form is set as the startup form, doesn't that imply it is the owning form for the application? If I use Main() shouldn't the Application.Run(New LaunchPad) set that form as the "owner"?

Comment: I also want to note I deleted and rebuilt the `obj` and `bin` folders to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing! When the user would login successfully, I had a call to close the login window. I used the `FormClosing` subroutine to check the reason why the window was closing. In the case where `e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing`, I called `Application.Exit()`. Apparently, `Me.Close()` set that user reason and the application would always quit. To resolve the problem, I added a local variable `_userClosedApp` to the login class that would be to `false` in the case where the application logic was closing the window. Adding in a check for this value corrected the issue.
Thank you all for your assistance in this matter!